# Configure Kube DNS when running Kubernetes via Docker

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to prepare a dev environment for my team, so we can develop, stage and deploy with the same (or near same) environment.

Getting a Kubernetes Cluster running locally via http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.html was nice and simple. I could then use kubectl to start the pods and services for my application.

However, the services IP addresses are going to be different each time you start up. Which is a problem, if your code needs to use them. In Google Container Engine kube DNS means you can access a service by name. Which means the code that uses the service can remain constant between deployments.

Now, I know we could piece together the IP and PORT via environment variables, but I wanted to have an identical set up as possible.

So I followed some instructions found in various places, both here and in the Kubernetes repo like [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns).

Sure enough with a little editing of the yml files KubeDNS starts up.

But an nslookup on kubernetes.default fails. The health check on the DNS also fails (because it can't resolve the test look up) and the instance is shut down and restarted.

Running `kubectl cluster-info` results in:

```
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080
KubeDNS is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
```

So all good. However, hitting that endpoint results in:

```
{
  kind: "Status",
  apiVersion: "v1",
  metadata: { },
  status: "Failure",
  message: "no endpoints available for "kube-dns"",
  code: 500
}
```

I am now at a loss, and know it is something obvious or easy to fix as it seems to all be working. Here is how I start up the cluster and DNS.

```
# Run etcd
docker run --net=host \
 -d gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.12 /usr/local/bin/etcd  \
 --addr=127.0.0.1:4001 --bind-addr=0.0.0.0:4001 --data-dir=/var/etcd/data

# Run the master
docker run \
    --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
    --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
    --volume=/dev:/dev \
    --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
    --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw \
    --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
    --net=host \
    --privileged=true \
    -d \
    gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.6 \
    /hyperkube kubelet --containerized --hostname-override="127.0.0.1" \
     --address="0.0.0.0" --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 \
      --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
      --cluster_dns=10.0.0.10  --cluster_domain=cluster.local

# Run the service proxy
docker run -d --net=host --privileged gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.6 \
 /hyperkube proxy --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --v=2

# forward local port - after this you should be able to user kubectl locally

machine=default; ssh -i ~/.docker/machine/machines/$machine/id_rsa docker@$(docker-machine ip $machine) -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

All the containers spin up ok, kubectl get nodes reports ok. Note I pass in the dns flags.

I then start the DNS rc with this file, which is the edited version from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/dns/skydns-rc.yaml.in)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: kube-dns-v9
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v9
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v9
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-dns
        version: v9
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: etcd
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.9
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        command:
        - /usr/local/bin/etcd
        - -data-dir
        - /var/etcd/data
        - -listen-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -advertise-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -initial-cluster-token
        - skydns-etcd
        volumeMounts:
        - name: etcd-storage
          mountPath: /var/etcd/data
      - name: kube2sky
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.11
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        args:
        # command = "/kube2sky"
        - -domain=cluster.local
      - name: skydns
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-10-13-8c72f8c
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        args:
        # command = "/skydns"
        - -machines=http://localhost:4001
        - -addr=0.0.0.0:53
        - -ns-rotate=false
        - -domain=cluster.local
        ports:
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns-tcp
          protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
      - name: healthz
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz:1.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
        args:
        - -cmd=nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1 >/dev/null
        - -port=8080
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: etcd-storage
        emptyDir: {}
      dnsPolicy: Default  # Don't use cluster DNS.
```

Then start the service (again based on the file in the [repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/dns/skydns-svc.yaml.in))

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    kubernetes.io/name: "KubeDNS"
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
  clusterIP:  10.0.0.10
  ports:
  - name: dns
    port: 53
    protocol: UDP
  - name: dns-tcp
    port: 53
    protocol: TCP
```

I made the assumption based on another SO question that clusterIP is the value I passed into the master, and not the ip of the host machine. I am sure it has to be something obvious or simple that I have missed. Anyone out there who can help?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I found [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12534) closed issue over in the GitHub repo. Seems I have an identical problem.

I have added to the thread on GitHub, and tried lots of things but still no progress. I tried using different images, but they had different errors (or the same error representing itself differently, I couldn't tell).

Everything relating to this that I have found suggests IP restrictions, or firewall/security settings. So I decided to curl the api from the container itself.

```
docker exec  49705c38846a  echo $(curl http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/v1/services?labels=)

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   908  100   908    0     0   314k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  443k
{ "kind": "ServiceList", "apiVersion": "v1", "metadata": { "selfLink": "/api/v1/services", "resourceVersion": "948" }, "items": [ { "metadata": { "name": "kubernetes", "namespace": "default", "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/kubernetes", "uid": "369a9307-796e-11e5-87de-7a0704d1fdad", "resourceVersion": "6", "creationTimestamp": "2015-10-23T10:09:57Z", "labels": { "component": "apiserver", "provider": "kubernetes" } }, "spec": { "ports": [ { "protocol": "TCP", "port": 443, "targetPort": 443, "nodePort": 0 } ], "clusterIP": "10.0.0.1", "type": "ClusterIP", "sessionAffinity": "None" }, "status": { "loadBalancer": {} } } ] }
```

Seems like a valid response to me, so why the JSON parse error coming from kube2Sky!?

```
Failed to list *api.Service: couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Failed to list *api.Endpoints: couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

Comment: The kube2sky issue was resolved by building a new image from kubernetes HEAD. DNS still not working though.

Comment: So now if you `kubectl get pods` do you find DNS?  If you aim `dig` or `nslookup` at that Pod's IP, does it work?

Comment: nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 172.17.0.3
   Server:    172.17.0.3
   Address 1: 172.17.0.3 kube-dns-v9-xm47z

   nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local'

Although I did note the following when running describe on the pod.

*Error syncing pod, skipping: DNS ResolvConfPath specified but does not exist. It could not be updated: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/602116c94ad34cdec8e07df13acd7a4cc7289d14dc287f11a6546f3734a6df8f/resolv.conf*

Comment: Try this:  Add `--volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:rw` to the docker command.  Even better, follow the updated docs and see if it works better.  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md

Comment: I have updated the docker commands, and sure enough the ResolvConfPath error goes away. However, still no joy. I want to rule out everything obvious, and could also see the cAdviser error, that has also been mentioned in various git hub threads. I built the lastest hyperkube from v1.1.1-beta.1, as the version in the docs was pre that fix/merge. 

So, everything is looking pretty healthy, but still no joy. So I decided to go back to using kube2sky:1.11 (not my built one) to rule anything out there. Boom Json parse error. From ssh on container. Seems it is hitting the healthz sidecar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the networking and kube2sky not accessing the API, so couldn't get the services.

Changing the docker run for the master from,

```
--config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests
```

to

```
--config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests-multi
```

Then in the skydns-rc.yaml the for kube2sky as well as setting the domain, set the host IP address.

```
- -kube_master_url=http://192.168.99.100:8080 #<- your docker machine IP
```

Without the manifests-multi, the host IP is not accessible.

This was a simple change but took a bit to track down.

I have created a simple set up on GitHub and will maintain this so people don't have to go through this pain just to get a local dev environment up and running.

https://github.com/justingrayston/kubernetes-docker-dns

Comment: You should not need the kube_master_url flag.

Start here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/10265#issuecomment-117267504

Specifically: check the `--service_account_key_file` and `--root-ca-file` flags on apiserver

Which install instructions are still getting this wrong?

Comment: @TimHockin Thanks.
Currently only using this set up locally so I can run applications as they are in Container engine and current set up works just fine but I will check that out and see what changes need to happen. 

As it is only local, my kube_master_url is http, I guess that is why it might be needed, but worth mentioning for those that may be deploying to a server and should be using https.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see any endpoints then most likely your `skydns` pod is not working. Try `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` to see what is the status.

`clusterIP` can be any IP address which is not used yet. It will be used to connect to DNS service. It should not be the host IP.

Comment: Thanks. Yup I figured clusterIP is the service IP for the kubedns. As I found in that GitHub issue, it is the kube2sky pod that is trying to lookup the api and is chucking out.

Failed to list *api.Endpoints: couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

So obviously not getting JSON. If you don't configure the HOST IP correctly you get connection refused, which I'd expect. Other services work fine. So I need to find out what is wrong with kube2sky. I am going to check to see if there is a new version.

Comment: Note, the clusterIP must be within the "service-cluster-ip-range", else you'll get an error.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263927/kubernetes-kube-dns-service-creation